# How to continuously monitor the number of occurences going through a pipe

Tags: bash, pipe, uniq

I have a script that captures packets and outputs the 2 digit country code linked to the newly found IP.

I want to monitor the number of packets for each country and do it in a continuous fashion during the packet capture.

The output of `uniq -c` is exactly what I need, but I want it to change over time and update while reading the output of the pipe.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash        
ngrep |grep -oE "[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}"  | while read i
    do
            whois $i | grep -i 'Country'  | sed 's/Country:[ ]*//I'

    done
```

Comment: I get a lot of 6..., ..4. with your grep. Try something like this ```grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'```  from here https://superuser.com/questions/202818/what-regular-expression-can-i-use-to-match-an-ip-address#202835?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You realise that you're making at least two `whois` requests (so sending many more packets and loading one or more whois sever somewhere) for every packet that goes through your network interface?

Here, I'd use `tshark` assuming the IP address geolocation database is installed and properly configured:

```
tshark -lq -T fields -e ip.geoip.src_country -e ip.geoip.dst_country |
  gawk -F '\t' -v clear="$(tput clear)" '
  BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"}
  {
    count[$1 ? $1 : "Unknown"]++
    count[$2 ? $2 : "Unknown"]++
    printf "%s", clear
    for (c in count)
      printf "%5d %s\n", count[c], c
  }'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `watch`:

```
./your_script > countries.txt
watch "sort countries.txt | uniq -c"
```

To speed up things you could do:

```
./your_script | awk '{seen[$0]++;
  for(c in seen) printf("%s:%d ", c,seen[c]); printf("\n")}' >countries.txt
watch "tail -n 1 countries.txt | tr ' ' '\n'"
```

BTW instead of `whois` you may try `geoiplookup`.

Comment: The file can be huge in long term running. I am sure there is a way to directly use the pipe output with `awk`. `awk '!seen[$0]++'` gives the newly occurrences for instance without having to use a file and apply `sort -u`

Comment: You just append updates to the output? Like `awk '{seen[$0]++; print $0,seen[$0];}'`